# Hyperlinks inside ListBox

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, listbox, vb.net-2010

[image: ScreenShot of my project]
Hello, can someone help me with my project that I'm working on? Anything is appreciated!

So, what do I need? Its simple, I need **link** and **name** bars to actually create a hyperlink into the LSB listbox. Can someone please help me??

PS: Could you please keep it simple for me, I just started with this language.

Comment: Does someone know how to actually do this????

Comment: Maybe add string and MouseDoubleClick event...?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK This isn't as simple as I would like it to be for you but here goes. I'll try to explain as I go along

OK all the bits code below goes in your Form1 class as one lump - without my explanations that is. What I've done here is create a new class called **Hyperlink**

It has a couple of  properties called **Name** and **Link** and a constructor called **New**

```
Class HyperLink
    Private friendlyName As String
    Private link As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return friendlyName
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String)
            friendlyName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property URL As String
        Get
            Return link
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            link = URL
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(nm As String, ln As String)
        friendlyName = nm
        link = ln
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here I'm creating list called **linkList** - this will hold the list of hyperlinks - I'm doing this so that later on the listbox will be set to use this as it's source of list items

```
Dim linklist As New List(Of HyperLink)
```

This sub called **addLinkToListbox** actually does several things. The important bits are that it tells you program to temporarily stop responding when the index of the listbox changes(which happens even when you're changing the contents off the listbox)

Then it adds a new **hyperlink* to the list of hyperlinks taking data from the link textbox and the name textbox.

To actually refresh the data shown in the textbox, I have to change the listbox datasource to **nothing** and then back to to the **linkList**

The next two lines tell the listbox to display the **Name** property inn the list box and when the item is actually clicked, to return the **URL** property.

Finally, I tell the program to start responding again when the index of the listbox index changes.

```
Private Sub addLinkToListbox(linkName As String, linkURL As String)
     RemoveHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
     linklist.Add(New HyperLink(linkName, linkURL))
     ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
     ListBox1.DataSource = linklist
     ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
     ListBox1.ValueMember = "URL"
     AddHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub
```

These last two bits of code are hopefully self-explanatory

```
    Private Sub btnAddLink_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddLink.Click
        addLinkToListbox(txtName.Text, txtLink.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler alternative to the accepted answer by using `ListViewItem`s:

```
Dim Item = New ListViewItem
Item.SubItems(0).Text = "name"
Item.SubItems(0).Tag = "<uri>"
ListView.Items.Add(Item)
```

And then to open the URI in the default browser:

```
Private Sub MyListView_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyListView.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim myProcess = New Process()
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sender.Items(0).SubItems(0).Tag
    myProcess.Start()
End Sub
```